# Avoid rendering all items in list view

Tags: react-native

As you can see I tried to init 5 items at first.
However, from the debugger console I could also see all the items are rendered which slows down my app performance!

Any idea?

## ListView

```
<SwipeListView
    initialListSize={5}
    dataSource={this.ds.cloneWithRows(this.props.words)}
    renderRow={this.renderWord.bind(this)}
    renderHiddenRow={(data, secId, rowId, rowMap) => this.renderDeleteAction(data, secId, rowId, rowMap)}
    disableRightSwipe={false}
    disableLeftSwipe={false}
    leftOpenValue={RIGHT_OPEN_WIDTH}
    rightOpenValue={-RIGHT_OPEN_WIDTH}
/>
```

## Cell/Item

```
render(){
    let startTime = Date.now();
    let detailView = this.computeDetailView()
    console.log(this.props.word);
    console.log(Date.now() - startTime);
    return(
        this.props.showDetail && detailView
    )
}
```

## console.log

[image: inline]

## Update

After updating to `FlatList`

[image: inline]

Original view

[image: inline]

Answer (score 0):

After looking into latest version of [react-native-swipe-list-view](https://github.com/jemise111/react-native-swipe-list-view), it used deprecated [`<ListView />`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html) that cannot change caching behavior.

*[open source code highlight](https://github.com/jemise111/react-native-swipe-list-view/blob/master/components/SwipeListView.js#L149)*

Modify its code to use [`<FlatList />`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html), then you can take advantage of its wrapping [`<VirtualizedList />`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/virtualizedlist.html#maxtorenderperbatch), grant access to props of [`windowSize`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/virtualizedlist.html#windowsize) and [`maxToRenderPerBatch`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/virtualizedlist.html#maxtorenderperbatch).

After that this should works

```js
<SwipeListView
  initialListSize={5}
  maxToRenderPerBatch={5}
  windowSize={10}
  dataSource={ds.cloneWithRows(words)}
  renderRow={(data) => {
    console.log('row', data);
    return <Text style={{height: 200}}>This is row {data}</Text>;
  }}
  renderHiddenRow={(data, secId, rowId, rowMap) => {
    console.log('hidden row', data);
    return <Text>This is hidden row {data}</Text>;
  }}
  disableRightSwipe={false}
  disableLeftSwipe={false}
  />
```

Comment: Thanks for your update. However, it doesn't work for showing list items

Comment: @newBike Why not work? Tested and works for me, with `console.log` on `renderRow()`.